# Dot Net Core 2.2 Sign Out issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

Have .Net Core 2.2 MVC application and integrated with Azure AD for userAzure AD. User authentication and sign out is working as expected.

But if we copy the cookies AspNetCore.AzureADCookie, .AspNetCore.AzureADCookieC1, .AspNetCore.AzureADCookieC2 from the authenticated browser session using the EditThisCookie extension and logout then if we import again those copied cookies back into browsers and we are able to access the application. Application trusting the application and login automatically.

I'm using NuGet Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI NuGet package

Is this behavior expected?

Comment: Updated the question with suggested changes.. Not sure if question can be opened again or should i be raising another question. Please help.